# UIAlertView Messages

Tags: iphone, nsstring, uialertview

Trying to include a instance variable in a message that a UIAlertView Shows.

```
lostAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry" message:(@"You Were Wrong, the correct structure was %@", structureName)  delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

however, when the Alert is shown, no message is shown.

Any ideas and help would be appreciated :)

Sam

Answer (score 6, accepted):

did you try it with:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"You Were Wrong, the correct structure was %@", structureName]
```

instead of

```
(@"You Were Wrong, the correct structure was %@", structureName)
```